# B+ Tree order of 1 & 2

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

I am confused regarding the maximum and minimum number of keys to be inserted in a B+ Tree having an order of 1 and order of 2.

In the videos I watch, it is said that the maximum number of keys to be inserted in a node (except the root) is at least *m* and at most *2m* (assuming *m* is the order).

According to these 2 statements, what is the minimum & maximum number of keys to be inserted in a B+ Tree, having an order of 1 and order of 2? I am not sure if the 2 statements above conflict, or I misunderstood something. Any idea?

Comment: start with not adding irrelevant tags, this will make your question ignored. This difinatelly isnt' question about C and javascript

Comment: The terminology in your sources seem slightly off. I'm used to `order` meaning the maximum number of  keys in a node, so a B+ Tree of order 4 would have between 2 and 4 keys in every node (except possibly for the root node).

Comment: What about the order 1 and 2? I need an example for them, because for order 1  >>> min 1, max 2 and for order 2 >>> min 2, max 4 keys are created. But according to your definition, in order 2 the max number of keys in a anode is 2. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, that would be it, presumably an order 1 and 2 tree (not that I've ever heard that term before) would have between 1 and 2 keys per page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having the reference to the video, it looks like they use a non-standard definition of the term *order*, which is the cause of the confusion.

The standard definition of *order* for a tree would be the maximum branching factor, i.e. the maximum number of children that a node may have. So, in that definition it is not the *minimum*, but the *maximum*, and it is not about the number of *keys*, but about the number of *children*.

The video's definition would mean that the maximum number of keys would always be an even number, while in reality there is no such requirement. B+ trees may well have a maximum branching factor that is even, making the maximum number of keys odd.

Using standard definition of the term *order*, we specifically have for B+ trees these constraints:

- Its internal nodes have at the most *m* children. This means that they have at the most *m - 1* keys.
- Its internal nodes have at least *m/2* (rounded upwards) children, except for the root:
- If its root is not a leaf, it may have as few as 2 children.
- Its leaves contain the actual data values.

Here is an example B+ tree with order 4 (standard definition), which corresponds to a B+ tree where the number of keys must be between 1 and 3 -- something that does not fit with the video's definition:

[image]

As you can see, a node can here at most have 4 children, and at most 3 keys.  In your definition where *2m* represents the maximum number of keys, the order is actually *2m+1*. So you are asking for examples of B+ trees of order 3 and 5, using the standard definition of *order*.

Here is an example of order 3 -- the lowest possible order for B+ trees -- which means the number of keys must be either 1 or 2 in each node:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Technically not an answer to the question

---

I am learning B+Tree as well through the book [Database System Concepts 7th edition](https://www.db-book.com/),  I would like to provide a B+Tree example where you can see the problem of the order of 2:

1. Create a B+Tree with order 2
2. Insert `1, 2, 3` to it

And eventually, you will get something like this:

```
      [3]
     /   \
  [2]    [ ]
  / \      \
[1]-[2] -- [3]
```

And you will notice that there is a node that is **empty**(has no keys). This is because, when first inserting `3` to the right lower `[2]`, we need to **copy** `3` to the parent node

```
  [2]
 /   \
[1] [2]

 [2]
 /   \
[1] [2, 3] # need split

  [2, 3]   # need split
  / \   \
[1]-[2]-[3]
```

This makes node `[2, 3]` full, thus we have to split it, since this is a non-leaf node, the key `3` will be **moved** to the parent node **instead of being copied** to it, resulting in an empty node.

```
      [3]
     /   \
  [2]    [ ]
  / \      \
[1]-[2] -- [3]
```

The above case can be summarized as: After splitting a non-leaf node, the new node (just created for splitting) has ONLY 1 key and you have to move this key to the parent node, resulting in an empty node.